# Forbidden You don't have permission to access

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I've created a directory named angular with an index.html file inside, and I get the error:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /angular/index.html on this server.

The solutions I have founded
Change the permissions to 755 and 777 to the folder and directory
Restart the service afted doing the first step

```
[felipe@felipe html]$ sudo service httpd start 
[sudo] password for felipe: 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  httpd.service 
[felipe@felipe html]$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwxrwx.  2 felipe felipe 4096 dic 19 19:33 angular
drwxr-xr-x. 12 felipe wheel  4096 abr 14  2013 phppgadmin
drwxr-xr-x.  5 felipe felipe 4096 ago 27 00:55 wordpress
drwxr-xr-x.  5 felipe felipe 4096 oct 12 17:18 yii
[felipe@felipe html]$ ls -l angular
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 felipe felipe 200 dic 19 19:19 index.html
```

Still getting this error, I have another folders and it works with no problems, i'm using fedora 22

Comment: Check the Apache error log file for your site. If you don't know its location look for a line that begins with **ErrorLog** log in Apache's **httpd.conf** file, which may be in the **/etc/httpd/conf/** directory. It will look something like `ErrorLog /var/apache2/logs/error_log`. Search for the entries in the error log file pertaining to access to that directory. Note: if you are using virtual hosts in the **httpd.conf** file, look for the **ErrorLog** line in the **VirtualHost** section for this particular website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is not file system permission error so do not try **chmod**, it is **Apache configuration error***

You need to make changes in your *Apache configuration* `httpd.conf` for this i.e.

```
Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
```

Open `httpd.conf` and find document root to either un-comment the above line or insert it

[image]

Comment: If he includes "Indexes" after "Options", he allows visitors to view the files in directories if he doesn't have an **index.html**. I don't think that is what he wants; I'd expect someone to [disable indexes](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/) unless he has a specific reason for allowing all the site's files to be perused even without links to them or without an **index.html** file in a directory. I assume, instead, that he expects the **index.html** file to be shown if someone uses **/angular/index.html** or **/angular** in the URL.

Comment: Well that is True + tricky. I mostly deal with that by using **<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied** & **<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted**